# Adding a filter to related posts not working

Tags: filters

I'm using the the filter below to filter related posts by author, I added an author ID to test but they are not filtering by author

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_related_posts', 'woo_custom_attribute_filter' );
function woo_custom_attribute_filter( $q ) {

            array(
            'orderby'        => 'rand',
            'posts_per_page' => $limit,
            'post_type'      => 'product',
            'author'        => 2,
            'fields'         => 'ids',
            'meta_query'     => $meta_query,
            'tax_query'      => array(
                'relation'      => 'OR',
                array(
                    'taxonomy'     => 'product_cat',
                    'field'        => 'id',
                    'terms'        => $cats_array
                ),
                array(
                    'taxonomy'     => 'product_tag',
                    'field'        => 'id',
                    'terms'        => $tags_array
                )
            )
        );
    //print_r($q);
    return $q;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$q` should contain the array:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_related_posts', 'woo_custom_attribute_filter', 10, 1 );
function woo_custom_attribute_filter( $q ) {
    $q = array( /* args here */ );
    return $q;
}
```